# Wireshark json's capture to spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, wireshark

I have a JSON file from wireshark that I need to load to Spark. I am using PySpark.

I need to extract data from those JSON files and then output that data as a json file too.

The problem is that I can't seem to load the JSON file correctly in a way that helps me with find each data. i tried `json.loads` , also the `SQLContext` in Spark.
Sqlcontext in spark won't help much because i want to adapt it to spark streaming module .
Json file looks something like this :

```
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2017-07-27",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.encap_type": "1",
          "frame.time": "May 13, 2004 11:17:09.864896000 Afr. centrale Ouest",
          "frame.offset_shift": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_epoch": "1084443429.864896000",
          "frame.time_delta": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_delta_displayed": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_relative": "2.553672000",
          "frame.number": "13",
          "frame.len": "89",
          "frame.cap_len": "89",
          "frame.marked": "0",
          "frame.ignored": "0",
          "frame.protocols": "eth:ethertype:ip:udp:dns",
          "frame.coloring_rule.name": "UDP",
          "frame.coloring_rule.string": "udp"
        },....]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("abc.json")     
import re
json_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : x[1])\
.map(lambda x : re.sub(r"\s+", "", x, \
flags=re.UNICODE))


printRdd(json_rdd)
df = spark.read.json(json_rdd)
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: Hey , i'm really greatful for you answer .Can you pleace tell me what does the "
printRdd(json_rdd)" line stand for it doesn't really work for me

Comment: def printRdd(rdd):
        for x in rdd.collect():
                print x

Just used to print the contents of the RDD.

Comment: thanks man , is the sql part how can i print the "frame.offset_shift" using "df.select("frame.offset_shift").show(1)" returns cannot resolve resolve frame.offset_shift given input columns :[_index,_score,_source,_type]

Comment: try 
df.select("_source.layers.frame.frame.offset_shift").show()

Comment: The point here frame.offset_shift is making it think that it's still in another layer there  once i removed the point it's working should i remove all the points from the file?